# When solving a recurrence relation how to determine if the result is a big O or a Big theta?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, recurrence

I'm solving some recurrences and I didn't quite understand when to put O or Theta on the result.
If I have a recurrence like this:

```
T(N)=2T(n/2)+n
```

and I solve this with the iterative method I know the result is an O (nlogn).

could I also use theta (nlogn)?
is there any verification I could do to establish this?

Comment: Hi. What is "the iterative method" and how do you know that the result is O(n log(n))?

Answer (score 0):

By definition,

```
If T(n) = O(g(n)) as well as T(n) = Ω(g(n)), 
then we can say that T(n) = Θ(g(n))
```

In case of `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n` you're dividing n inputs into two branches and then merging those inputs from bottom up. This method is also known as **Divide and Conquer**.

So for every branch you're doing `n` operations. How many number of times? That is the height of the tree. For binary tree here, the height is `log_2(n)`. Thus the total operations you're doing is at most `n * log_2(n)`.

Since the height of the tree is fixed and the number of operations performed is also fixed so the total operations you'll be doing is also at least `n * log_2(n)`.

Thus for your above function, `T(n) = Θ(n * log_2(n))`.

Comment: Thank you, you have been very kind. But if I wanted to think in a more general way and not in this specific case, is there a rule that tells me when to use theta or O?

Comment: because if t (n) = O (g (n)) and t (n) = omega (g (n)) then it is a theta. But in this case the limit f (n) / g (n) how do I do it? what are my functions f (n) and g (n)?

Comment: @mimmolg99 please do check out master's theorem. This kind of recurrence relation can be easily solved by master's theorem. It clearly mentions when T(n) will be Big-Oh, Big-Omega and Big-Theta.